# Why are some paths followed by a ",0" (a comma and a zero) on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, path

Sometimes in Windows I come across some paths, between some quotes or not, that are followed by a `,0` (basically a comma and a number). It's not necessary 0 it could be 1, 3, 5 or any other number but the one I see the most is 0.

Here are some examples I found in the Window Registry:

```
C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\gimp-2.10.exe,0
C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\gimp-2.10.exe,1
C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.bin,7
"C:\WINDOWS\py.exe",1
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe",0
```

All the examples I found were inside a `DefaultIcon` key in the Windows Registry. The last one can be seen at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VLC.mp4\DefaultIcon`:

```
Name             Type           Data
(Default)        REG_SZ         "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe",0
```

What do they do?

Comment: What is the context of these paths exactly?  They appearing in the registry isn't enough information

Comment: PROBABLY, the reason for this is it the offset to find the icon for what is going to be displayed in the explorer.  Go to the exe.. find the 0th (aka first) icon in the resource.. or 1, .. or 7.

Comment: that's not a path but a pair of information

Comment: This is a path, in a way, but also, it's two separate pieces of information: the path to the file, and the location of something INSIDE the file. When you select a new icon for something and go through the system dialog with loads of icons, you're not looking at individual files, bit at lots of icons embedded inside a single file. That number tells which icon you've chosen inside that file.